# Solving DE's With Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I understand the general method, but sometimes I'm not getting the right solution. For instance take this example:

$y'' - 2y' - 3y = -3te^{-t}$

I thought the particular solution would be of the form:

$Y_p(t) = (At + B)e^{-t}$ but this doesn't work. I've tried a couple variations and none of them work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please find complementary solution/associated homogeneous solution before finding particular solution.

Comment: @Moo: you mean idonknow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this has characteristic equation: $r^2 -2r -3 = 0$, which has roots $3$ and $-1$. The reason why your guess is wrong is that $-1$, which is the exponent in front of the exponential, appears as a root (consult a textbook if you are unsure of this theorem). Hence we must multiply the original guess by $t$, getting $Y_p(t) = t(A_0 + A_1t)e^{-t}$, which works.